# how to use TTreeReader in PyROOT

Tags: python, root-framework, pyroot

I'm trying to get up and running using the TTreeReader approach to reading TTrees in PyROOT. As a guide, I am using the ROOT 6 Analysis Workshop (http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/7-using-ttreereader) and its associated ROOT file (http://root.cern.ch/root/files/tutorials/mockupx.root).

```
from ROOT import *
fileName = "mockupx.root"
file = TFile(fileName)
tree = file.Get("MyTree")
treeReader = TTreeReader("MyTree", file)
```

After this, I am a bit lost. I attempt to access variable information using the TTreeReader object and it doesn't quite work:

```
>>> rvMissingET = TTreeReaderValue(treeReader, "missingET")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/ROOT/v6-03-01/root/lib/ROOT.py", line 198, in __call__
    result = _root.MakeRootTemplateClass( *newargs )
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

`TTreeReaderValue` is a templated class, as shown in the example on the [`TTreeReader`](http://root.cern.ch/root/htmldoc/TTreeReaderValue.html) documentation, so you need to specify the template type.

You can do this with

```
rvMissingET = ROOT.TTreeReaderValue(ROOT.Double)(treeReader, "missingET")
```

The [Python built-ins](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) can be used for `int` and `float` types, e.g.

```
rvInt = ROOT.TTreeReaderValue(int)(treeReader, "intBranch")
rvFloat = ROOT.TTreeReaderValue(float)(treeReader, "floatBranch")
```

Also note that [using `TTreeReader` in PyROOT is not recommended](http://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=18822#p80184). (If you're looking for faster ntuple branch access in Python, you might look in to the [`Ntuple`](https://github.com/alexpearce/Ntuple) class I wrote.)